# How to have a particular address load with a label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-apps-email

We use webmail for my company (using gmail).  It is correctly set to throw anything that comes into `@joebowcompany.com` into the main processing account.

Without labeling recipients and without creating a new account, is there a way to have a particular address label itself?  In other words, all orders coming into `completedwork@joeblowcompany.com` would label itself completed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a *filter* that applies the required label.

If you have one of these emails open, you can select "Filter messages like this" from the dropdown menu. Or, go to the main (cog) menu > Settings > Filters > Create a new filter.

Specify the appropriate "To" address and on the next page choose "Apply the label".